# Active MQ Pending messages on fail-over in Master Slave architecture

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, failover

**Background:**

We have master(AMQ1)/slave(AMQ2) configuration for active MQ.
We have multiple applications deployed using failover, in this some applications will publish/consume and some applications will consumes/publish the JSM messages.

Out of these we have one APPLICATION1 which publishes messages(say 1000) every 30 sec(we have a trigger to pull records from DB and Publish and update DB record status ONE BY ONE) to TOPIC A. 
Another APPLICATION2 which has consumer on TOPIC A consume and store in another Database ONE BY ONE.

failover:(tcp://AMQ1:61616,tcp://AMQ2:61616)?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1&timeout=5000

**Technical Details:** Applications are developed with have 
-   Transaction manager as bitronix to make sure 2PC is taken care.
-   Spring Boot application 1.3.X
-   Active MQ 5.14.X
-   Camel version 2.16.X , application use java config and we create Camel JmsComponent(camel routs) with Pooled Connection Factory.

**Problems:** 
When APPLICATION2 application is deployed it creates a consumer to AMQ say  ID_Cosnumer-1001.  When APPLICATION1 publishes messages APPLICATION2  is consuming and 2PC is working fine we are not loosing any messages and we do not see any duplicate messages.
Problems starts when a failover happens on AMQ Master-AMQ1, when failover happen AMQ2 became master and AMQ1 becomes Slave. During this process another consumer is created for APPLICATION2 with ID_Cosnumer-2002 and ID_Cosnumer-1001 is not killed. Both are visible in AMQ browser consumer section.

- **Problem 1:** Because of this some messages in flight are staying in pending state(probably associated to ID_Cosnumer-1001) and are not consumed by the APPLICATION2  and we are missing these transactions, how to overcome this problem?

  - **Problem2:**  Randomly , may be when again a failover happens(when masters switch) these messages are consumed. Due to this messages are in out of order state.
  - **Problem3:**  Is it common that failover happens quite frequently? Why do they happen?
  - All new messages are getting consumed without any problem.

Thank you all in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a better guarantee of delivery than straight topics. Either use a durable subscriber, or look to Virtual Topics (produce to a topic, consume from a queue). This will improve the transactionality behavior (messages rollback on consume), and queues have a better ordering guarantee than topics without a durable subscriber.

ref [Virtual Topics](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html)

Comment: Thank you for your time Matt .  We are using Virtualtopic while publishing messages.  We are not loosing message but they are not processed as soon as they are received by consumer(say if i publish 10,000 messages and at that moment failover happens 1 or 2 messages are stuck in pending status). And now i could see two  consumers in AMQ consumer section.  We have setup AMQ in such a way that always a Consumer Queue will have only one consumer.